# Remove "[string]" from BUILD_LOG_REGEX extracted lines

Tags: jenkins

Here is my sample string.

[echo] The SampleProject solution currently has 85% code coverage.

My desired output should be.

The SampleProject solution currently has 85% code coverage.

Btw, I had this out because I'm getting through the logs in my CI using Jenkins.

Any help? Thanks..

Answer (score 5):

You can try `substText` parameter in `BUILD_LOG_REGEX` token to substitute the text matching your `regex`

> New optional arg: ${BUILD_LOG_REGEX, regex, linesBefore, linesAfter, maxMatches, showTruncatedLines, **substText**} which allows substituting text for the matched regex. This is particularly useful when the text contains references to capture groups (i.e. $1, $2, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Using below will remove prefix [echo] from all of your logs ,

${BUILD_LOG_REGEX, regex="^\[echo] (.*)$", maxMatches=0, showTruncatedLines=false, substText="$1"}

Answer (score 0):

`\[[^\]]*\]` will match the bit you want to remove.  Just use a string replace function to replace that bit with an empty string.

Comment: Thanks andrew, but is there a way to use regex? Because I'm using ${BUILD_LOG_REGEX, regex="regex code", linesBefore=0, linesAfter=0, maxMatches=1, showTruncatedLines=false, escapeHtml=true} in jenkins token plugin.

Comment: The code I gave is regex.  I don't know how to plug it into Jenkins.

Comment: It's ok thanks btw. I can solve this using your solution but the problem I cant corporate it with jenkins token reference like this: ${BUILD_LOG_REGEX, regex="regex code", linesBefore=0, linesAfter=0, maxMatches=1, showTruncatedLines=false, escapeHtml=true}

Answer (score -2):

Andrew has the right idea, but with Perl-style regex syntaxes (which includes Java's built-in regex engine), you can do even better:

```
str.replaceAll("\\[.*?\\]", "");
```

(i.e., use the matching expression `\[.*?\]`. The `?` specifies minimal match: so it will finish matching upon the first `]` found.)

Comment: thanks for the help but I'm using a token plugin jenkins like :  ${BUILD_LOG_REGEX, regex="regex code", linesBefore=0, linesAfter=0, maxMatches=1, showTruncatedLines=false, escapeHtml=true} how can i use replaceAll here?

Comment: Then just use `\[.*?\]` in your regex expression, I guess. Sorry, I'm not an expert in Jenkins.

Comment: Thanks it works but as I said. I need to incorporate it with jenkins token reference. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Old but as I was looking for the same thing, this finds a "Email was triggered for: success" string and returns only "success" using subsText:
`${BUILD_LOG_REGEX, regex = "^Email\\s+was\\s+triggered\\s+for:\\s+Success", substText="Success", showTruncatedLines=false}`